# Sending messages between embed iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the basic structure of my page(s)
How would I send a message "downwards" using window.postMessage from myModule1.js to myModule2.js. I can't seem to get the hierarchy correct.
The messaging binding etc is not a problem, just can't work out document.xxx.yyy.
There are no X domain issues etc.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>myModule1.js</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="1">
        <iframe id="frame1">

            <div id="2">

                <iframe id="frame2">
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <script>myModule2.js</script>
                        </head>
                        <body>

                        </body>
                    </html>
                </iframe>
            </div>

        </iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can select the different frames from `window.frames`

Comment: Cheers :  window.frames[0].frames[0].postMessage()